# Rotation-switched active rectifier idea

Tags: mosfet, rectifier, three-phase

Most of you will know how three-phase rectification works and how cool it is.

My idea is: replacing the diodes in a three-phase full-wave diode bridge with MOSFETs, as in active rectification, and switching the MOSFETs depending on the rotation angle of the generator. Say, using a Hall-effect sensor to trigger switching.

It sounds feasible in my head - but then a lot of things do ... so I thought I'd run this idea by the pros first.

Comment: Uh..... why not just use comparators triggered by the incoming line voltage? They make ICs specifically for controlling active rectifiers, you know.

Comment: Well, that's one way to go about it. I'm looking into that too. ^_^

The ICs I've seen aren't remotely cheap, especially in India, where I am. Not to mention optimized for high-power throughput. I was thinking a position-switched system could be modular and a bit more reliable than a voltage comparator since the RMS voltage changes with rotation speed.

Comment: Leakage inductance in the generator will, under heavier or lighter load conditions, alter the phase angle of the voltage produced relative to mechanical position. I'm not suggesting this is a show stopper but you need to consider the implications.

Comment: If you really want to get into this, you should research regenerative braking systems for electric vehicles. Not only do they rectify the voltage, they can tightly control the amount of power that is drawn from the alternator. You can also do PFC.

Comment: Why, rectifiers don't waste as much power as an "active" rectifier. I don't see what is gained by adding complication to a circuit, just to see if it can be done.

Comment: @Andyaka: Agreed. I wouldn't think it much of an issue, but I'll keep it in mind. The system in this case is:
Generator --> Rectifier --> Battery
so the AC side is minimal.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Thanks for the tip. I've read up a little on regen. braking, but most systems in use seem to be proprietary. I'll dig a bit harder then ^_^

Comment: @Optionparty: True, it's not as simple as a diode bridge, but it's not altogether complicated. My impression is that, no matter what the speed of the generator, there would be specific angles of the rotor that correspond to the zero-crossing of the voltage waveform. So, in addition to reducing the diode voltage drop, switching the MOSFETs based on those angles would make a modular, ultrafast system that works at all voltages.